AUCTeX cannot find a working TeX distribution (again)
This is DIFFERENT from many other questions about "AUCTeX cannot find a working TeX distribution" because the TeXlive binaries ARE in my Emacs' "PATH" environment variable.

I have installed TeXLive using Suse's package manager (zypper) and all the binaries are placed in /usr/bin
$ ls /usr/bin/*tex*
/usr/bin/akonadi_html_to_text  /usr/bin/latex-dev       /usr/bin/pdflatex-dev    /usr/bin/texconfig-dialog
/usr/bin/dvilualatex           /usr/bin/luahbtex        /usr/bin/pdftex          /usr/bin/texconfig-sys
...
/usr/bin/htxetex               /usr/bin/pdfetex         /usr/bin/tex4ht
/usr/bin/latex                 /usr/bin/pdflatex        /usr/bin/texconfig
$

and, in the same instance of Emacs in which I tried to use AuCTeX I have
(getenv "PATH")
"/home/boffi/.local/bin:/home/boffi/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
;                                                      ^^^^^^^^

but, when I tried to compile-and-view my source file AuCTeX replied
ERROR: AUCTeX cannot find a working TeX distribution.
Make sure you have one and that TeX binaries are in PATH environment variable.

I'm puzzled. Any ideas?

Details please: what are you doing exactly and what error message(s) are you getting as a result? Check your *Messages* buffer to see if there are any more details - and edit your question to add all the requested information.

Is it not in the title?

No - you needed to provide the exact error message you get plus the recipe of what exactly you are doing when you get that error message. I see you now have done that.

Yes - it is in the title. However...

In your *scratch* buffer, type (call-process "/bin/sh" nil nil nil "-c" "tex") and press C-j after it. Does it say 127? If so, your emacs does not know how to find your tex program.

See exec-path: that should be initialized from your PATH but if not, you get the problem you report. You can patch it up manually by adding "/usr/bin" to it, but you should probably investigate what causes it to misbehave and fix the root cause.

What is the output of M-: (executable-find "tex")?

@mxnt I've solved the mystery, thank to your hint. AUCTeX is not checking for  xelatex (what I'm using) or pdflatex but is checking for tex. Suse, in its mysterious wisdom, when I installed TeXlive, specifying --no-recommends, did not install /usr/bin/tex!!! I've installed texlive-tex and noe everything is fine. I'll write an answer asap. Again, thank you!

TL;DR
$ sudo zypper install -no-recommends texlive
$ sudo zypper install -no-recommends texlive-tex


A comment by mxnt prompted me to guess that AUCTeX was not checking for the program I instructed it to use to compile my source (xelatex) but was checking for tex.
Just to be sure, overly sure, I typed tex at the shell prompt and this happened
$ tex

The program 'tex' can be found in following packages:
  * texlive-tex-bin [ path: /usr/bin/tex, repository: download.opensuse.org-oss ]
  * texlive-tex-bin [ path: /usr/bin/tex, repository: openSUSE-20210302-0 ]

Try installing with:
    sudo zypper install <selected_package>

$

I installed TeXlive as follows
$ sudo zypper install --no-recommends texlive

and I had an installation comprising latex, pdflatex, and xelatex but Suse, in its mysterious wisdom, choosed to not install tex.
Eventually I
$ sudo zypper install -no-recommends texlive-tex

and now AUCTeX works as it should do.
I'd like to add that, while AUCTeX was searching in vain for tex, Preview worked just fine, even if it comes from the same factory...
